# Backpropagation along a particular path in a network with PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, gradient, backpropagation

[image]

In PyTorch, by applying torch.autograd on loss function we get gradient for all the layers in neural network. I have a doubt that suppose I want to compute gradient over a particular path. Is there any way to do so in PyTorch?
In the above figure, suppose we have to compute ∂L/∂x where L is loss function and x is the data, and  also the gradient should be along only the path specified in red color (there should not be contribution to the gradients due to other possible paths)?

Comment: Maybe try to eliminate unwanted neurons during the forward pass? One can multiply in every layer an additional matrix whose elements corresponding to the desired path stay at 1; otherwise, set it to 0. The idea is similar to dropout but in a heuristic way.